# Display image json object into ionic list ( v2)

Tags: json, ionic2

I have a json object that contains id of an image and its url in the server , in order to display it in an ion-list i try the code below but the image doesn't appear.

About.html

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <img [src]="post.pic"/>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

here is my json object :

```
{"ListeImages":[{"id":"44","pic":"https:\/\/stationpfe.000webhostapp.com\/projet\/uploads\/1494201248244.jpg"}],"success":1}
```

About.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Imageservice} from '../../providers/imageservice';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html',
  providers:[Imageservice]
})
export class AboutPage {
posts: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public im:Imageservice,public http: Http) {
this.getImages();
 
  }

getImages(){
this.im.OneArrive().subscribe(response=>
{
  this.posts=response.ListeImages;
});

}
}
```

imageservice.ts ( provider)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class Imageservice {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Imageservice Provider');
  }
public OneArrive(){
var url='https://stationpfe.000webhostapp.com/projet/SelectListeImages.php';
     return this.http.get(url).map(res=>res.json()); 
}
}
```

Comment: check the value of img src chrome console, if the url is not displayed there, the prvblm with ur json,

Comment: set an error callback in your subscribe

Comment: Set a console.log on this.posts, did the data actually returned or did you request returns an error? Like @suraji said, set a error callback to catch any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-avatar item-left>

      <img [src]="imageUrl+card.image" />
</ion-avatar>
```

i have stored the image url in .ts file the card.image value is the value that i get from server.
In my case i have a server storage=>http://311.11.111.111:8000/storage<=like this
i specify the storage + the value from api to display in the
     `<img [scr]=""/>` specified above.
Hope it helps....

[image]